# The correct way for Vue condition to add a css class

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

What is the correct way to add a css class decided by a condition in Vue:

```
<div class={{current == key ? ' is-active' : '' }}> Page title</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<div :class="{'is-active': current === key }">
```

You just use an object where each class you desire is the key, and the value is the comparator.

Answer (score 1):

This is the most convenient way to me, you can add multiple classes using conditions

```
<div :class="[current === key ? 'is-active' : '', otherClassCondition ? 'other-class' : '']">
```